# Looping through Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a program to simulate an airline reservation system. I an supposed to use an array of type boolean to represent the number of seats. First five seats represent first class and last five represent economy. Initially the program must allow the user to make a choice between first class and economy and then his choice is processed as follows: 
A user can only be assigned an empty seat in the class he chooses.
Once a class is full, the user is offered the option to move to the next class
If the user agrees to move to the next class a simple boarding pass is printed.
If the user refuses to move to the next class. The time for the next flight is displayed. i would appreciate help on how to loop through the elements of the array to determine whether its true of false. Also i am trying to display the number of seats available in each class before the user makes a selection this is what i've written so far.. My code is far from complete, i acknowledge that, i am a novice programmer please help. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirlineReservation 
{ 
private boolean[] seats =;  // array to hold seating capacity
private String AirlineName; // name of airline 
private int[] counter = new int[5]

// constructor to initialize name and seats 
public Airline(String name, boolean[] capacity )
{
    AirlineName = name;
    seats = capacity;
} // end constructor 

// method to set the Airline name
public void setName( String name )
{
    AirlineName = name; // store the course name
} // end method setCourseName

// method to retreive the course name 
public String getName()
{ 
    return AirlineName;
} // end method getName

// display a welcome message to the Airline user 
public void displayMessage()
{
    // display welcome message to the user 
    System.out.printf("Welcome to the Self-Service menu for\n%s!\n\n",
        getName() );
} // end method displayMessage

// processUserRequest 
public void processUserRequest() 
{
    // output welcome message 
    displayMessage();

    // call methods statusA and StatusB 
    System.out.printf("\n%s %d:\n%s %d:\n\n",
        "Number of available seats in First class category is:", statusA(),
        "Number of available seats in Economy is", statusB() );

    // call method choice
    choice(); 

    // call method determine availability
    availability();

    // call method boarding pass
    boardingPass();
} // end method processUserRequest

public int statusA() 
{
    for ( int counter = 0; counter <= (seats.length)/2; counter++ )
} // revisit method 

// method to ask users choice 
public String choice()
{
    System.out.printf(" Enter 0 to select First Class or 1 to select Economy:")
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    boolean choice = input.nextBoolean();   
} // end method choice

// method to check availability of user request
public String availability()
{
    if ( input == 0)
        System.out.printf("You have been assigned seat number \t%d", seats[ counter ]);
    else 
        System.out.printf("You have been assigned seat number \t%d", seats[ counter ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony : As you are novice, hence please look at following comments :
 1. Be specific while asking your question. In this case the question was "how to loop through array!". You posted complete problem statement.
 2. Please google it or research it properly on internet if similar question has been asked by anybody before. In this case, similar question can be find here :
 [Iterate through string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707695/iterate-through-string-array-in-java)

Because of these reasons people are giving your query downvote!

Now just want to provide answer to your question as you look quite new to programming :

```
    boolean flag[] = {true,false,true,false};
    for(int i=0;i<flag.length;i++){
        System.out.println(flag[i]);
    }
```

I hope it helps!