# To remove 3 consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I need to remove 3 consecutive integers, done with the code but i am not able to print the last index number. can you please help me out..

here is the code..

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] list={ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9};
    for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++)
    {
        if((list[i]==list[i+1]) )
        {
            if(list[i]==list[i+2])
            {
                i=i+2;
                continue;
            }
           System.out.print(list[i]) ;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print(list[i]);
        }
    }
    }  
}
```

Comment: "but i am not able to print the last index" look at the condition on the for loop, "`i<list.length-1`".

Comment: You should also change the 8 to a 9 in the array initializer, and see how that goes.

Comment: now i am getting arrayOutOfBound exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Dr.Will in his/her [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64770675#64766440), one of the problems in your code is the check `i < list.length`.
Anyway, it's not the only one: you are accessing `[i+1]` and `[i+2]` elements without checking if those two values are acceptable indexes.

I just want to add some hint:

1. Use a debugger while writing such algorithms (it may save you A LOT of time)
2. cache the value of intermediate results, to avoid multiple access to the same element of the array
3. cache the size of the array, for the same reason, or use a reverse loop (which has some [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707695/iterate-through-string-array-in-java/55706319#55706319))

The result would look something like this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] list = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9}; // sample list
        int len = list.length;
        if(len < 3)
          return;  // avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        
        // forward loop
        System.out.println("Forward loop:");
        int elem1;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
          elem1 = list[i];
          if(i+1 < len && elem1 != list[i+1])
            System.out.println(elem1);
          else if (i+2 < len && elem1 == list[i+2] && ++i < len){
            // note that "&&" in java is a shot-circuit "AND", so the last "++i" will not be executed if not necessary
            // also note that i'm not incrementing "+2", because the for loop will add another "+1" just after this "continue" statement
            continue;
          } else
            System.out.println(elem1);
        }
        
        // reverse loop
        System.out.println("\nReverse loop (if the order is not that relevant):");
        for(int i = len; --i >= 0;){
            elem1 = list[i];
            if(i-1 >= 0 && elem1 != list[i-1])
                System.out.println(elem1);
            else if(i-2 >= 0 && elem1 == list[i-2] && --i >= 0)
                continue;
            else
                System.out.println(elem1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your logic, your logic is good and also slightly look complicated, but i changed or edited one line after referring your logic, this seems not much complicated as your logic but gives same result.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your logic (–Marco Carlo Moriggi), your logic is helpful and also slightly look complicated, but i changed or edited one line after referring your logic, this seems not much complicated as your logic but gives same result.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] list={ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9};
    int elem = list.length;
    for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++)
    {
        if((i+2<elem) && (list[i]==list[i+1]) )
        {
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  ") ;
            if(list[i]==list[i+2])
            {
                i=i+2;
                continue;
            }
           
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the `i<list.length-1` clause. Your lis.length will return a value of 13, if i remember how to count, adding the -1, you are giving a value of 12, and if you add the <, you´re telling the `i` to only reach the 11 position.

So i think the solution could be either one of these:

`for(int i=0; i<=list.length-1;i++)`

or

`for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++)`

Comment: after changing i am getting ArrayOutOfBound Exception..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Tried with ArrayList 

public class PrintSequence {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
int []a = {4,2,3,1,7,5,6,7,4,1,2,3,8,9,6};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(4);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(6);
        List<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            int temp = list.get(i)+1;
            int next = list.get(i)+2;
            for(int j=i+1; j<list.size();j++){
                if(list.get(i+1)==temp && list.get(i+2)==next){
                    if(!seq.contains(list.get(i))){
                        seq.add(list.get(i));
                        seq.add(list.get(i+1));
                        seq.add(list.get(i+2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(seq);
    }
}
```

output -
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]